# SQL Date range Question

Tags: sql

I want to show data from the last month (not form months past though), this month and any futures data in my report.  In a SQL view, how can you do this with the date fields called date?

Comment: What SQL implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively in SQL Server you could use this simple comparison:

```
…
WHERE DateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
…
```

Comment: I +1'd from your original comment on my answer.  Pretty large logical issue that you addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server, in which case use the `DATEDIFF` function to see if the date in your table is within the range you want to display.

Information on the function can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score -1):

there is a built in function in SQL Server to add the date .. and for your date field named as date select it as `[date]`

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  This is like someone asking how to change the oil in their car and your response is "You just change it".